# Django - How many simultaneous requests are possible

Tags: django

I have a Django app running on Heroku. At the moment I only have 1 dyno. One of the urls generates a pdf from database values and this takes about 4 seconds. Since I only have 1 dyno, does it mean that while the pdf is busy generating, my dyno can't respond to any other requests from any other users?

In other words, how many open requests can Django/Heroku handle at a given time?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure how I would even test it?

Comment: How about to just open that URL twice, preferably in two browsers, at the same time?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos-and-requests

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestions. So my app can in fact only handle 1 request at a time, so I need to see how this can be fixed. I'm already using gunicorn which is what Heroku recommends

Comment: Found what I was looking for: I need to set WEB_CONCURRENCY as an environmental variable.